# Jquery setting transform-origin to center

Tags: jquery

I'm having troubles with setting the transform-origin of a div to the center of the site.

This is what I have so far:

```
var xPos = ($(window).outerWidth() - $('#pointer').outerWidth())/2;
var yPos = ($(window).outerHeight() - $('#pointer').outerHeight())/2;

var xPosSTR = xPos+"px";
var yPosSTR = yPos+"px";

$('#pointer').css(
        {
        '-moz-transform-origin': 'xPosSTR yPosSTR',                
        'transform-origin':'xPosSTR yPosSTR',                   
        '-ms-transform-origin':'xPosSTR yPosSTR',                                
        '-webkit-transform-origin':'xPosSTR yPosSTR',
        });
```

I hope someone can help me :)

have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform origin accept % or property right,center and others

and in `var xPosSTR = xPos+"px";` you have a PX.
See the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: thanks, is there a way to calculate px into %? I'm having 170px, but I don't know how to turn them into percent

Comment: « *The transform origin accept % or property right,center and others* » — maybe the page has changed since you linked to it, [but the very first example value is `2px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Syntax). [The values section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Values) describes *length* before it describes *percentage*.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this thread. For anyone else trying to solve this with the original posters solution please include Zpx-value aswell (third parameter) and it will work with jQuery.

Example:

```
var xPosSTR = 200 + 'px';
var yPosSTR = 500 + 'px';

$('.element').css({
    'transform-origin':         xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR + ' 0px',
    '-webkit-transform-origin': xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR + ' 0px'
});
```

And forgive the ugly JS ;)

Comment: thank you so much! My zoomed image was wandering all over the page, and then I added the z value and it started behaving sensibly. Explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 0):

It is because you put single quotes around your xPosSTR and yPosSTR variables. The following code should work:

```
var xPos = ($(window).outerWidth() - $('#pointer').outerWidth())/2;
var yPos = ($(window).outerHeight() - $('#pointer').outerHeight())/2;

var xPosSTR = xPos+"px";
var yPosSTR = yPos+"px";

$('#pointer').css(
        {
        '-moz-transform-origin': xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR,                
        'transform-origin': xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR,                   
        '-ms-transform-origin': xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR                 
        '-webkit-transform-origin': xPosSTR + ' ' + yPosSTR
        });
```

or a simpler version:

```
var xPos = ($(window).outerWidth() - $('#pointer').outerWidth())/2;
var yPos = ($(window).outerHeight() - $('#pointer').outerHeight())/2;

var origin = xPos + "px " + yPos + "px";

$('#pointer').css(
        {
        '-moz-transform-origin': origin,                
        'transform-origin': origin,                   
        '-ms-transform-origin': origin,                 
        '-webkit-transform-origin': origin
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but here is your answer:   set the container||image or what ever you want to rotate to:

```
div {position:fixed or absolute, then top:50%; left:50%;        transform:translate(-50%. -50%); }
```

Now append a class to the image||container lets call the class this

```
.rotateandcenterme {
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 }
```

I had this problem few years back, and eventually solved it like this.. remember to keep the translate() in-front of the rotate()