# How can i set transformOrigin in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform

How can i set the css code transform-origin: x y z; in jquery?

```
  var val = 1.1;
  $("#click").css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + val + ')' });
```

it works well and i also want to set transform Origin in Jquery, not in css.

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $("click").css({"transformOrigin": "20 50"})
});

$("click").css({"transformOrigin": "center"})
$("click").css({transformOrigin: "center 20 50"})
```

Comment: `$('click')` needs to be `$('#click')`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: upps,  yes.. i forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:
`$("#click").css( "transformOrigin", "center" );`

Comment: var val = 100 + 'px; var owl = 200 + 'px' ////  If i want to set with 2 variables ? .. i tried with one , $("#click").css("transformOrigin", val); it works //// but not with 2 $("#click").css("transformOrigin", val owl );

Comment: okay i found it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144211/jquery-setting-transform-origin-to-center